# Transportation problem with complication

Tags: optimization

I have a transportation problem with complication. Essense of complication -- shipping is carried out with a trucks. Each truck has limited capacity. Each truck has the same capacity. Let's call capacity of eack truck -- K.

How to reduce this problem to the linear programming problem?

Comment: Are you essentially transporting numbers of trucks?

Comment: Yes. For example, if K=3. And we need to transport 10 goods from one point(i) to another(j), we need 4 trucks (3 full and 1 truck just with one good). Summary cost will be 4*C_ij, Where C is a matrix of costs.

Answer (score 0):

If all trucks have the same capacity and cost, you can solve the classical transportation problem, and then divide the total cost by the capacity. Take the ceiling of this number, and it will give you the number of trucks you need (and thus the cost as well).